# Writing post to another user in their profile using PHP and MySQL table structure

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make like Facebook while you can write posts to your friends in their profile. I know how to do the post system but I don't know how I can write in another user's profile page I just want to know the table structure of writing to another user.

Comment: Zuckerberg must be quaking in his boots

Answer (score 0):

The following SQL creates a table called "posts".  You can then store the id of the user that creates the post in "author_id" and the id of the user on who's profile the post is placed in "profile_id".

```
CREATE  TABLE `posts` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  `author_id` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  `profile_id` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  `content` TEXT NOT NULL ,
  `created` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC) );
```

Then to get all the posts on a particular user's profile you would use:

```
SELECT * 
FROM posts
WHERE profile_id = 1
ORDER BY created DESC;
```

(here I have retrieved the posts for the user with id=1 and ordered them so that the most recent will be at the top of the list)